# How to completely remove jdk 1.8 from Macbook? Scala Webapps Project

Tags: java, macos, scala, java-7, xsbt-web-plugin

Thanks for reading my question. I've been struggling with this for more than 8 hours. On my macbook, I had JDK 6, 7, and 8 installed with 8 being default. I had a need this morning to create a scala/sbt webapp project (to package to a .war) to deploy on tomcat7 for a simple test application.

Only Requirement: **Project must be able to run on JRE 1.7 & Tomcat 7**

I have not been able to do it because of Unsupported major.minor and countless other problems with versioning and terrible giter8 templates.

Here's my current dilemma:

Followed all the steps in "Starting From Scratch" section up until `sbt jetty:start jetty:join`. (Skip to last code snippet for error): 
 https://github.com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin/blob/master/docs/3.0.x.md

Here's my **java home and version**:

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home
$
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)
```

Here's my **build.sbt**:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies += "javax.servlet" % "javax.servlet-api" % "3.0.1" % "provided"

enablePlugins(JettyPlugin)
```

Here's my **project/build.sbt**:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.earldouglas" % "xsbt-web-plugin" % "3.0.3")
```

Here's my **project/build.properties**:

```
sbt.version=0.13.8
```

servlet.scala and web.xml are exactly as they are in the link.

Here's my **project structure**:

```
.
├── build.sbt
├── project
│   ├── build.properties
│   └── build.sbt
└── src
    └── main
        ├── scala
        │   └── servlets.scala
        └── webapp
            └── WEB-INF
                └── web.xml

6 directories, 5 files
```

Here's the **BANE OF MY EXISTENCE**:

```
$ sbt jetty:start jetty:join
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/dan/Projects/temp/ssltester/project
[info] Updating {file:/Users/dan/Projects/temp/ssltester/project/}ssltester-build...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Set current project to ssltester (in build file:/Users/dan/Projects/temp/ssltester/)
[info] Updating {file:/Users/dan/Projects/temp/ssltester/}ssltester...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/dan/Projects/temp/ssltester/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[info] Packaging /Users/dan/Projects/temp/ssltester/target/scala-2.11/ssltester_2.11-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] starting server ...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/eclipse/jetty/runner/Runner : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
[success] Total time: 3 s, completed Nov 7, 2017 6:58:47 PM
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Nov 7, 2017 6:58:48 PM
[info] waiting for server to shut down...
```

**Could someone please point out to me what's wrong? ** I completely deleted the java 1.8 jdk directory. Since it says `version 52 (jdk 8)` I don't know where it's coming from. jdk 7 should be `51`, jdk 6 should be `50`

If you're in Denver, I'll buy you a beer (if you're over 21) otherwise it's soda for you kid! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/eclipse/jetty/runner/Runner : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

My guess is that the version of Jetty that you're using was compiled for Java 8, which won't work if you're using Java 7.  In xsbt-web-plugin 3.0.x, the [default Jetty version](https://github.com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin/blob/master/docs/3.0.x.md#jetty-version) is 9.  Based on [this table](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Starting/Jetty_Version_Comparison_Table), you might want to try Jetty 8 (or older) instead.

Try adding this to your *build.sbt*:

```
containerLibs in Jetty := Seq("org.mortbay.jetty" % "jetty-runner" % "8.0.0.v20110901" intransitive())
```

Since your requirements include being able to run your project under Tomcat, you may prefer to [use Tomcat instead of Jetty](https://github.com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin/blob/master/docs/3.0.x.md#quick-reference).  The [default version of Tomcat is 8](https://github.com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin/blob/master/docs/3.0.x.md#tomcat-version), which looks like it should work with Java 7 according to [this table](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html).

To switch to Tomcat, change `enablePlugins(JettyPlugin)` to `enablePlugins(TomcatPlugin)` in your sbt configuration, and change `jetty:start jetty:join` to `tomcat:start tomcat:join` at the sbt prompt.

Comment: Holy crap! The man himself! I did not expect this! I put my laptop down because I was going to throw out the window. This question was my last hurrah. tomcat:start tomcat:join works perfectly. I have no idea why I didn't think of that. Awesome work on this plugin! Do you mind if I add a pull request tomorrow about adding that point (that you can do tomcat instead of jetty) on your docs?

Comment: You live in Boulder? I'm definitely buying you a beer. I go to CU Boulder Leeds school of business! Small-world. Thanks for the answer by the way.

Comment: Cool!  I'm glad you got it working.  Improving the docs is a great idea; feel free to open a PR.